# Autocorrelation theory for GAMMS?

Tags: mixed-model, references, autocorrelation

I know how to model autocorrelation in a normal linear model with mixed effects.

However, the function `gamms` also allows us to model the correlation structure of many other distributions than the normal.

Where can I read the theory underlying this general, non-normal case?

For the normal case, I have read [Mixed effect Models in S and S plus](http://verde.esalq.usp.br/~jorge/cursos/modelos_longitudinais/Mixed%20Effects%20Models%20in%20S%20and%20S-Plus.pdf).